# Source maps are not properly showed in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, source-maps, cra

[image: Console on Chrome]

I was wondering why the first and the second lines are referring to instrument.js but the third line can properly show the source which is Toolbar.tsx. Source maps are generated by webpack. How can I make it show the correct sources?

Answer (score 1):

Both are different errors

1. In `instrument.ts` 123rd line . When you do list.map() give `key` property for each of the list item which is unique
2. In `Toolbar.tsx` 10th line .
   It is related to `onClick` event of Toolbar, and it is saying the html unknownelement during callback function execution